# streamingContentKeyRequestData returns error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12158

Tags: swift, hlsl, drm, fairplay

I am trying to setup Fairplay + HLS following Apple sample code. However I see the error when I call streamingContentKeyRequestData

```
let certUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "fairplay", ofType: "der")!)
let applicationCertificate = try? Data(contentsOf: certUrl)

guard let contentKeyIdentifierURL = resourceLoadingRequest.request.url,
           let assetIDString = contentKeyIdentifierURL.host,
           let assetIDData = assetIDString.data(using: .utf8) else {
               print("Failed to get url or assetIDString for the request object of the resource.")
               return
       }

let spcData = try resourceLoadingRequest.streamingContentKeyRequestData(forApp: applicationCertificate,
                                                                                       contentIdentifier: assetIDData,
                                                                                       options: nil)
```

It will always throw the error

```
Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11800 "The operation could not be completed" UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=An unknown error occurred (-12158), NSLocalizedDescription=The operation could not be completed, NSUnderlyingError=0x2823e5710 {Error Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12158 "(null)"}}
```

I checked applicationCertificate is not nil, assetIDData is not nil. Not sure what else I need to in order to make it work. Is this an issue from my cert or how I create Data from file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Offline HLS Fairplay playback error when the app is closed, code 16227](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47579882/offline-hls-fairplay-playback-error-when-the-app-is-closed-code-16227)

Comment: Have you implemented your AVAssetResourceLoader? Also note that Apple recommends not storing your certificate in the app bundle.

Comment: I was using avcontentkeysession, the issue disappeared after couple tries, so I really do not know what cause the issue